# Ace Editor HTML Live Syntax checking

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

I'm using Ace Editor, and I'm trying to figure out how to get it to live syntax check the HTML markup in the editor.

If I set it to javascript using:

```
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

The live syntax checking (all the little Xs and Is on the left side) works completely fine.

However, If I change it back to HTML using

```
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
```

I only get the default editor with code completion for HTML, but no live syntax check.

I know this can be done because on HTML version of the Kitchen Sink (http://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html), it shows the code syntax checking if I don't use proper markup.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest version and make sure [worker-html.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/worker-html.js) file is present.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific file "worker-(languageName)" in the folder provided by the Ace Library. You just have to add that file in the folder where you have the "ace.js" file stored for your project. The Live Syntax Checking will start working in your project.